# Loading Web Pages into Panels + reading the raw source code of another script

Tags: google-apps-script

Ok, so this questions has two parts, and it's a dozy.

What I'm trying to do is create a web app that splits the screen in half, where one half is the Google Apps Script editor for another script, and the other half contains the result of that script executing.

Here's what I need help with:

1) Assuming you already know the URL you want to load, how do you load another website into a panel in an active web app?

2) Assuming you already know the key for the file, how do you retrieve that raw source code from a file saved onto the user's drive?